# The impact of broken links in PDFs - how it affects site ranking

Tags: links, pdf

So I know that Google frowns upon broken links on web pages.

But how does Google feel about broken links *inside* PDFs on my website?

What I'm trying to figure out is if my site's ranking will be penalised if Google spiders my PDFs and finds broken links inside them.

Thanks.

Comment: Pagerank in regard to search does not take into account PDFs. Why? Because they did not originally exist when Pagerank was conceived. Pagerank rank pages as in HTML pages. Not resources. So no. No worries.

Comment: @closetnoc Links in PDFs do pass PageRank.   I recall a scandal where somebody was distributing a discount catalog in PDF format to educational institutions.   Many of the edus would put it on their website so their staff could download it and order from it.   The PDF was stuffed with anchor rich links that caused the products to rank #1 until Google penalized them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Wow! That is news to me. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Google has also confirmed that PDF links pass PageRank: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-pdf-links-pagerank-20573.html

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Humbled. Something I missed. I left my comment so yours make sense. If you want, you can remove them all. Cheers!!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I did realize that Google followed links in PDFs, however, it was my working model that resources were not used for ranking. While I understand the logic in using the PDF links for ranking, personally, if I were building a search engine, I feel that I would stick with HTML pages only. Less risk.